# Closed form of ${_2}{F}_1\left(\frac{1}{2},s,\frac{3}{2};-\frac{1}{a^2}\right)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, closed-form, hypergeometric-function

While solving an integral, I came acorss the term
$$ \tilde{I}(a,s)= {_2}{F}_1\left(\frac{1}{2},s,\frac{3}{2};-\frac{1}{a^2}\right).$$
To be precise, it came in the following calculations
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1} \left(1+\frac{t^2}{a^2}\right)^{-s}dt &= \int_{0}^{1} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dbinom{s+n-1}{n}(-1)^n\left(\frac{t}{a}\right)^{2n}dt \\
& = \int_{0}^{1} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(s+n)}{\Gamma(s)}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\left(\frac{t}{a}\right)^{2n}dt \\
     &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma(s+n)}{\Gamma(s)}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \frac{1}{a^{2n}}\int_{0}^{1} t^{2n}dt \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma(s+n)}{\Gamma(s)}\frac{\Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}\frac{\left(\frac{-1}{a^2}\right)^n}{n!} \\
     &=  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(s)_n\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_n}{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)_n}\frac{\left(\frac{-1}{a^2}\right)^n}{n!} = {_2}{F}_1\left(\frac{1}{2},s,\frac{3}{2};-\frac{1}{a^2}\right)
\end{align*}
I would like to know if this expression can be simplified more for certain values of $a>0$ and $0<s<1$. I believe there is a simpler form when $s=\frac{1}{2}$ or $a=1$.

Comment: This is the [incomplete beta function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html). For $s=\frac14$, it can give an elliptic integral. There does not seem to be much else.

Comment: For $s=1/2$ is: $\mathrm{arcsinh}\! \left(\frac{1}{a}\right) a$.

Comment: If you can type it as an answer I will accept it. @Tyma